# Allowing a user to access specific models in admin

Tags: django, permissions, admin, models

If I had a model similar to this:

```
class Dealer(models.Model):

    name        = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    other_name  = models.CharField(max_length=10,  blank=True, null=True)
... etc.
```

If I wanted to create a user that can sign in to the admin site and only have access to edit this model only, how could I go about doing this?

I have looked around and haven't been able to successfully get it to work. I have also looked into packages such as guardian but had no success. What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can deal with permissions to allow him to only see this model. Each user can be assigned a group, where a group has a limited set of permissions and a user can also have a set of permissions available. You just need to put this user as a "Staff" user (`is_staff = 1`) and then put him every permission about the `Dealer` model.

[image: Admin permissions right for one user]

If the user isn't a superuser, he will see only links to the `Dealer` model. Everything about [permissions and authorization are presented in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

> The Django admin site uses permissions as follows:
>
> - Access to view the “add” form and add an object is limited to users with the “add” permission for that type of object.
> - Access to view the change list, view the “change” form and change an object is limited to users with the “change” permission for that type of object.
> - Access to delete an object is limited to users with the “delete” permission for that type of object.
>
> Permissions can be set not only per type of object, but also per specific object instance. By using the `has_add_permission()`, `has_change_permission()` and `has_delete_permission()` methods provided by the `ModelAdmin` class, it is possible to customize permissions for different object instances of the same type.